# Position epigraph at the end of the page

Tags: positioning, epigraphs

I want to create a epigraph. But the package `epigraph` position it at the beginning of the page. I want to position the epigraph at the end of the page. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The question that @MarcoG has cited should indeed answer yours as well.  So, would you mind if I propose to close this question as a duplicate?